# Trying a simple RSI strategy resulting in compile time error

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to achieve the following:

> This strategy will be using the 5 minute timeframe.
>
> "Enter a long position if the 5 period RSI is below 30, price is above the 200 EMA and the 1 minute MACD crosses up".
>
> "Close all open positions if the 5 period RSI crosses below 70 after being overbought, or if price drops by more than 1%"

[image]

Here is what I tried to do, but it didn't work out. The part with `request.security_lower_tf` is giving a compile time error.

```
//@version=5
strategy("RSI strategy", overlay = true, commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, currency = currency.USD, commission_value = 0.075, slippage = 2, initial_capital = 1000)

// RSI
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 5)

// MACD
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
macd = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "1", macdLine)
signal = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "1", signalLine)
hist = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "1", histLine)

// EMA
ema = ta.ema(close, 200)



// Inputs and variables
orderStake = input.int(90, 'Order Stake (%)', minval=0, step=1) / 100
var float entryPrice = na

rsiRising = input.int(5, minval=1, title="RSI's Moving Average is rising for x candles")
myRSI = ta.ema(ta.rsi(close,14),14)

cond1 = ta.rising(myRSI,rsiRising)
rsiLessThan = input.int(80,step=1,title="RSI Must be lower than x")
cond2 = ta.rsi(close,14) < rsiLessThan
//enterLong = cond1 and cond2






if bar_index == last_bar_index - 1
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(macd))

enterLong = rsi < 30 and close > ema //and macd > signal


orderSize = strategy.equity * orderStake / close 
if orderSize > 1000000000
    orderSize := 1000000000

// Trailing Stoploss
i_activationPct = input.float(2.45, title='Trailing Stop is activated after price moves x% from Entry', step=0.1) / 100
i_trailOffset = input.float(153560, title='Trailing Stop in ticks', minval=1, step=10)

var float activationLevel = na  // The price needs to pass this price in order to activate the trailing Stop Loss
i_sl = input.float(8.5, title='Stop Loss (%)', step=0.1) / 100
var float stopLossPrice = na

// Enter long
var float ticks = na
if enterLong and strategy.opentrades == 0
    entryPrice := close
    stopLossPrice := entryPrice * (1 - i_sl)
    strategy.entry('Open Long Position', strategy.long, orderSize, when=strategy.position_size <= 0, comment='Long')
    activationLevel := entryPrice + entryPrice * i_activationPct
    strategy.exit('Open Long Position', stop=stopLossPrice, trail_price=activationLevel, trail_offset=i_trailOffset, comment='Long Stop')

// Plots
var tstop = float(na)
if close > activationLevel and strategy.opentrades > 0
    tstop := math.max(high - i_trailOffset * syminfo.mintick, nz(tstop[1]))
    tstop
else
    tstop := na
    tstop

useSellSignal = input(true, title='Use Sell Signal')
sellSignalProfit = input.float(0.6, minval=0, step=0.1, title="Sell with at least x% profit")/100
exitWithProfit = (close - entryPrice) / close > sellSignalProfit
exitCond = myRSI < myRSI[1]

if useSellSignal
    if exitCond and close < activationLevel and exitWithProfit
        strategy.close('Open Long Position', comment='Sell Signal')

showPlots = input(defval=true, title='Show Plots')
plot(showPlots ? entryPrice : na, 'entryPrice', style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.new(color.purple, 0))
plot(showPlots ? activationLevel : na, 'activationLevel', style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.new(color.blue, 0))
plot(showPlots ? stopLossPrice : na, 'stoploss', style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
plot(showPlots ? tstop : na, 'Trailing Stoploss', style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.new(color.white, 0))
//plot(syminfo.mintick, title="mintick")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to call the actual ta.macd() in the security call. Because the 'macdLine' variable is giving you a float value. You can't call the lower timeframe of a floating point number (there isn't one).

You can use a tuple for the variable name and just use one request.security().  I haven't tried it. But that's what I'd recommend trying.